How to further improve AR Image Tracking in Unity AR-Foundation?
Problem:
Unity AR Foundation's image tracking is very unstable;
The placed AR objects move, rotate or float away over time.
What are your advices?
(E.g. Tips, Settings, Code-Adjustments, …)
Thanks, for your help!
Already tried:

Best Practice

Test everthing with the original AR-Samples-Project from Unity (tested different version up to the latest)
Set Project Settings from Setup-Instruction (ARFoundation, ARCore, ARKit)
Set Size of Image in ReferenceImageLibrary (in Unity and XCode)
Use images with a resolution of at least 300x300px
Images as PNG and JPEG
No Compressions


Other Things:

Different combinations of Versions of Unity, ARFoundation, ARCore and ARKit, Android, iOS
Different Images for Tracking
Different Models for Placement
Different Phones
Editor

XROrigin > Tracking Origin Mode: Set from Device to Floor
XROrigin > Main Camera > AR Camera Manager: Different Settings of Light Estimation and Render Mode


Unity Project Settings

Turn On/Off Plugin-Providers ARCore and ARKit
Turn On/Off Multi-Threaded Rendering
Use Fix in ProjectValidation  XR Plugin Management


Set Target-Framerate in Code (Application.targetFrameRate = 60;)
Checked Image-Tracker-Quality with Googles Tool arcoreimg (looks good, values over 75)
Added Anchors (At Prefab in Editor as Anchor-Component and from script at Instatiation (AddComponent))
Image-Tracker fills most of the Camera-Screen
Check XCode for Image-Quality-Warnings (no Warnings)
Tested in different lighting conditions
Debugged

Tracking-States are correct
Tested imaged in grayscale histogram (shows wide spread histogram)





